# Não consigo colocar um dado do banco em um value de um input do meu form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trata-se de um CRUD em php em que a única opção que falta é a edição de um cadastro, acontece que pretendo utilizar o mesmo `form` que uso para cadastrar para que a edição dos dados aconteçam. O problema é que quando clico em editar os campos de `value` dos inputs permanecem vazios que é o valor que eu defini por padrão. Vamos ao código:

[image: Formulário para cadastro com a tabela dos cadastrados]

Inputs da página acima:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nome?>" maxlength="70">
<input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $senha?>" maxlength="25">
```

Link do botão Editar: (Obs: idusuario não está entre aspas pois tudo já esta sendo tratado como string)

```
<a class='btn btn-info' href='processaDados.php?editar=$row[idusuario]'>Editar</a>
```

Código do arquivo processaDados.php que já é executado no momento em que a página é carregada:

```
session_start();

$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=db_CRUD;host=localhost", "root", "");

$nome = '';
$senha = '';
```

Código do arquivo processaDados.php que é executado quando o botão Editar é acionado:

```
if (isset($_GET['editar'])) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_dados WHERE idusuario = :ID");
    $stmt->bindParam(":ID", $id);
    $id = (int) $_GET['editar'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $nome = $results[0]["desnome"];
    $senha = $results[0]["dessenha"];

    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Coloquei apenas as principais partes do código para ficar mais simplificado e por que sei que o problema está nesse trecho acima. Vale ressaltar que já testei o último código fora do `if` e imprimi os valores recebidos em `processaDados.php` (retirei o header("`location: index.php`");), ou seja, estou recebendo o nome e senha quando clico em editar, mas o problema é quando tento atribuir esses valores aos `values` dos inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nossa eu já estava tão perto da resposta. É só remover o `header("location: index.php");` por que ao colocar essa linha de código eu estava redefinindo o valor de `$nome` e `$senha` a vazio, pois o `$_GET['editar']` voltava a não existir. Além disso como precisava manter na página atual troquei o link Editar `<a class='btn btn-info' href='processaDados.php?editar=$row[idusuario]'>Editar</a>` por `<a class='btn btn-info' href='?editar=$row[idusuario]'>Editar</a>`